# Save stored prodeure result as file

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, silverlight-5.0

i have a **Stored Procedure** , in proc  **Print** certain result like

```
Print '-- Start Transection--'
Print 'Transection No = ' + @TransectionId     
...
...
Print 'Transection Success'
Print '-- End Transection--'
```

is it possible to Save printed result in a file while call it from UI. after that we have to mail that file to user also ask for download that file

Answer (score 0):

PRINT is for logging and debugging purposes and shouldn't be used to return anything to the caller.

Here's a suggestion: instead of PRINTing, write into a logging table and return a loggingID. Then, query this table from your app and write to a file.

Example: create two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Logging
(
    LoggingID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Created datetime    
)

CREATE TABLE LoggingDetail
(
    LoggingDetailID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LoggingID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Logging,
    LoggingText varchar(500)
)
```

At the beginning of a transaction, create a new loggingID:

```
INSERT INTO Logging (Created) VALUES (GETUTCDATE())
DECLARE @loggingID INT = @@IDENTITY
```

Instead of PRINTing the logging messsages, do something like

```
INSERT INTO LoggingDetail (LoggingID, LoggingText) VALUES (@loggingID,
'-- Start Transection--')
```

At the end of your sproc, return @loggingID to the caller. You can now get retrieve the log messages from the LoggingDetail table and write them to a file:

```
SELECT LoggingText FROM LoggingDetail WHERE LoggingID=<loggingID> ORDER BY LoggingDetailID
```

Might be a good idea to encapsulate the INSERTs in separate sprocs. Those sprocs then can write to the log tables *and* PRINT the log messages.